# Perforce : can I change the comment associated with a p4 integrate?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

Is it possible to change the comment associated with a `p4 integrate` after I have done the integrate? The integrate itself is fine but the comment associated with it needs improving.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit any change (also submitted ones, at least for newer Perforce versions (at least 2009.2)) with

```
p4 -c <client-name> change <change-number>
```

Make sure $EDITOR is set.

Comment: For a submitted change, pass '-u' to 'p4 change.

Answer (score 2):

If using P4V or P4Win, you can just select the submitted changelist, right click, & select 'Edit'.